# How to create a "in-between" webservice in VS2010

Tags: c#, web-services

The ERP application we use has webservices but not with the functionalities we want.

So we would like to build an in-between webservice which forwards the request to ERP. And sends the result back without the requester, to even noticing, the difference. We don't know how the wsdl will look. It can be a list of customers, or one item. thats not important.

Is this something you have done/seen before? I have looked for examples everywhere I can think of. The code im trying to do it now with, just reacts as a webrequests.

I would like to show the visitor an adjusted wsdl from the ERP webservice and it has to be modified a little bit to accept a simple login en from then on forward the requests.

I was thinking the visitor logs in first and after a check receives a session id. This session id needs to be added always into an extra header value with the original webservice. These I will translate to the ERP webservice.

Hope someone has seen such an implementation and give me some hints/links.

The webservice can run in ASP but I prefer it to be a simple service in Windows.

Comment: You want a web service to consume and consolidate other web services - maybe adding some new features as well? *The webservice can run in ASP but I prefer it to be a simple service in Windows.* This doesn't make sense, either. A **web service** must be hosted on some web server.

Comment: Sounds like you are attempting to "extend" the web service. If that's your question the answer is no. You will need to write your own web service with your own interface for any of your own methods. Unless you have the code of the original web service and modify that.

Comment: I've done this a bunch of times, you need to make a web service that creates a web request to another service.  You can use a HttpWebRequest to call you ERP service, consume and change the results, and return it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/ImplementsamultithreadedWebproxyserver.htm

Don't know if it will work in production but it looks to be passing it all thru.. 
Please comment if you see issues with this?!